# Несколько значений разных типов в одном ключе

Tags: c#

Я не знаю, как правильно сформулировать вопрос, напишу как есть.

Допустим, я хочу сделать "объект", содержащий в себе несколько строго упорядоченных переменных разных типов данных, значения которых можно было бы изменять.
Что-то типа такого:

```
myObj = int,int, bool, string, string;
```

Есть ли в сишарпе такой велосипед?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: класс, структура не?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [Кортеж](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var myObj = new Tuple<int, int, bool, string, string>(5, 3, true, "text", "string");
```

или:

```
var myObj = Tuple.Create(5, 3, true, "text", "string");
```

Обращаться к компонентам кортежа затем можно так: `myObj.Item1`, `myObj.Item3`

Одно из преимуществ использования кортежей - у них "правильно" работает условие эквивалентности "из коробки", т.е:

```
new Tuple<int, int, bool, string, string>(5, 3, true, "text", "string") == new Tuple<int, int, bool, string, string>(5, 3, true, "text", "string")
```

вернет `true`, это полезно, когда вы используете кортежи, например, в качестве ключей словарей

В случае же с отдельным классом, как предлагают ниже, вам придется еще и перегрузить операторы `==` и `!=`

Но использовать кортежи стоит осторожно - сильное увлечение ими может значительно снизить читабельность кода!

Comment: Кортежи immutable.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Velosiped
{
  public int a;
  public int b;
  public bool c;
  public string d;
  public string e;
}
```

Так и знал - тупл, трупл, четверупл. "Какой моральный человек" добровольно такое в продакшен вставит?

Comment: A чем плох Tuple? Думаю автор вопроса знает о классах. Почему не предложить тогда структуру?

Comment: Честно говоря, классы я пока не писал с нуля. Поэкспериментирую пока с этим способом, не смотря на то, что его заминусовали.

Comment: @user2455111 Он плох всем. Мое мнение - вводя этого ублюдка, авторы поощряют низменные инстинкты - или идут у них на поводу.

Comment: @Igor какой развернутый ответ, придется поверить на слово

Comment: @Igor вы правы, всегда нужно использовать классы, но вот реальный пример. Есть программа, которая формирует и отправляет определенные файлы контрагенту, всего у нас 40+ отделов и из каждого из них уходят файлы, счетчики хранятся в словаре `Dictionary<int, int>`. Но потом выясняется что таких контрагентов может быть несколько и для каждого счетчик должен быть отдельный. Замена словаря на `Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int>` позволяет решить проблему за 3 минуты. Введение же нового класса более трудоемко, а дать ему вменяемое имя вообще проблема.

Comment: @Андрей вот еще интересное мнение нашел: "Разница между кортежем и классом в том, что кортеж не имеет имен свойств. Это почти всегда плохо, и я хотел бы использовать кортеж только, когда аргументы бессмысленны, как в абстрактной математике формулы, абстрактное исчисление размеров 5,6,7 или использовать кортеж для координат."

Comment: @FullyRetarded Ахахахах, в таком случае, этот способ только и нужно использовать, на этом все и строится ;)

Comment: Ваш пример тоже в продакшн ставить нельзя, за открытые поля  руки отрывать надо. Сильно подозреваю, что минус вы именно за это получили. Замените хотя бы на автосвойства, а лучше пример и автоматического, и обычного свойства.